# Using a manufacturer specific Profile and Cluster on NXP JN5168

Tags: zigbee, nxp, jennic

I am writing a ZigBee application on [NXP JN5168](http://www.nxp.com/techzones/wireless-connectivity/jn51xx.html) MCU.

I would like to create a custom Endpoint with a custom Cluster defined by me instead of one from the ZigBee Cluster Library.
Looks like I'm forced by the SDK **(1)** to use either the full ZigBee Smart Energy profile or Home Automation profile. NXP's [ZigBee PRO Smart Energy API User Guide - Appendix B](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/JN-UG-3059.pdf) states that I can setup custom Endpoints by declaring the appropriate data structures, calling a function to create the Endpoint and then calling the function `eZCL_Register()`.
I found all functions to create supported clusters from ZigBee Cluster Library but I cannot see wich function to call to create a custom cluster, if any exists.

I checked their [ZigBee PRO stack User Guide](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/JN-UG-3048.pdf) and nothing is said about custom cluster creation.
What I've found is an [old example](http://www.jennic.com/support/support_files/jn-an-1122_zbpro_home_sensor_demo) for the previous family of chips (JN514x) wich uses custom profile and clusters but it's pretty much useless.

Any help on this topic will be appreciated. If it cannot be accomplished (e.g. no real support for customization or Manufacturer Specific Clusters) a denial will be helpful too.

**(1)** I remember reading somewhere that the "pure" (without standard profiles) ZigBee Pro stack use is deprecated or not supported on newer JN516x chip family.

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with this chip but it is possible with Microchips's solution, where you can modify the source code of the stack if you don't have to pass zigbee alliance cerifitication.

Comment: I cannot change chip, this is a requirement in our project. I am rewriting an application from scratch and it is working, but not as I would like it to work.